# Update subviews of UIView from ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns

I have a `UIViewController` that implements a custom `UIView`, so;

```
override func loadView() {
    view = CustomView()
}
```

The custom view has a few lables and buttons and all the normal stuff, problem is in my viewController I have a request, and when that request is done, I'd like to update some of those lables/buttons.

Right now, in my `CustomView`, I have functions, such as;

```
func updateView() {
    labelOne.isHidden = true
    LabelTwo.isHidden = false
}
```

So I call the appropriate function from my viewController when the request is done.

This works, but it feels wrong, is there a neater way to update the subviews of my custom UIView, from my viewController? Should I maybe be using protocols or delegates?

Comment: Why does it feel wrong? Updating views is what a `ViewController` should be doing. It _controls_ the views after all.

Comment: @Sweeper updating the view doesn't, just the way of doing it, maybe I'm just paranoid

Comment: What kinda of data do you get back from the request? - do you have a nice object that you could pass to your custom view to trigger the changes?

Comment: @klskl what way? calling a method on `view`? That’s totally normal. You can find a lot of methods in UIKit that directly updates a `UIView` subclass.

Comment: @Wez yes I do have a response model, I'll most likely pass that in one of those functions, then update the view accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I've found quite neat in the past is passing the model directly to the custom view, then using `didSet` to trigger updates.

```
class CustomView: UIView {

    let labelOne = UILabel()
    let labelTwo = UILabel()

    var object:CustomObject! {
        didSet {
            self.labelOne.text = object.name
            self.labelTwo.text = object.description
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

This means in your `UIViewController` you can do the request and then pass the model straight to the custom view.

```
RequestHelper.getObject() { object in
    self.customView.object = object
}
```

Obviously here I'm guessing at your request and object names but hopefully you get the idea.